# LiDAR DSM: difference between Return 1 and First of Many?

Tags: raster, dem, lidar

I'm making a DSM for an urban LiDAR dataset; I understand these typically are also referred to as "first return" rasters- I don't quite understand the difference though between Return 1 and First of Many, both of which are present in the dataset. Which should be used for a DSM?

Comment: First returns are all the first returns. First of many are the first returns from pulses that return more that one return.

Comment: Yes. You should use both for DSM. Mostly Return 1 are hard surfaces (ground, buildings, etc) and First of many are first points usually of vegetation.